# Transition.each in d3 doesn't interpolate attributes

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js

I'm missing something in my understanding here rather than a bug I think...

In d3, I'm trying to update multiple attribute values within a transition. Using multiple `transition.attr` declarations works fine. But I'd like to use `.each` as in the real world I have a big calculation I don't want to do twice or more... I tried using `transition.each` but the attribute values don't interpolate.

Is it the `d3.select` within the `each`? I tried `d3.active` but that didn't do anything.

(There is a https://github.com/d3/d3-selection-multi library that supplied `.attrs` that worked nicely up to v5, but not with the new v6...)

See https://jsfiddle.net/f679a4yj/3/ - what I can do to get the animation but through the `.each`, what am I not getting?

Comment: Put the transition in the each function?

Comment: If you just want to make the `each` function works, try (put transition in each)[https://jsfiddle.net/tswLjkon/1/ ], but I think this works similar to the `sepAttr()`

Comment: aha to both, I hadn't thought of that way round. Though would this not kick off an individual transition per element rather than one transition over a bunch of elements? Which I'm guessing might not be as efficient 'under the hood'?

Comment: I'm not sure you can pass the selection with the transition and duration through to the each function. You can pass the node, but that doesn't seem to carry the transition with it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem here is a misconception regarding `transition.each`: you cannot use it to wrap several `transition.attr` or `transition.style` methods. In fact, it is used only to invoke arbitrary code to each element in that transition, just like `selection.each`.

Therefore, when you do...

```
.each (function (d, i) {
    // complicated stuff with d I don't want to do twice
    d3.select(this)
       .attr("x", ((zz+i)%4) *20)
       .attr("y", ((zz+i)%4) *40)
})
```

... you are simply changing the attribute in the DOM element, and the element will immediately jump to the new `x` and `y` position, as expected. In other words, that `d3.select(this).attr(...` in your code is a `selection.attr`, not a `transition.attr`.

You have several alternatives (for avoiding redundant complex calculations). If you want to stick with `transition.each`, you can use it to create a new local variable, or maybe a new property. For that to work, we need to have objects as the data elements in the array, and then we just use `transition.attr` as usual:

```
.each(function(d, i) {
  d.complexValue = ((zz + i) % 4) * 20;
})
.attr("x", function(d) {
  return d.complexValue;
})
//etc...
```

Here is a demo:

```js
const sel = d3.select("svg")
  .selectAll(null)
  .data([{
    color: "red"
  }, {
    color: "blue"
  }, {
    color: "green"
  }, {
    color: "yellow"
  }])
  .enter()
  .append("rect")
  .attr("width", 30)
  .attr("height", 30)
  .attr("x", function(d, i) {
    return i * 20;
  })
  .attr("y", function(d, i) {
    return i * 40;
  })
  .style("fill", function(d) {
    return d.color;
  });

let zz = 0;

function each() {
  zz++;
  d3.selectAll("rect")
    .transition()
    .duration(1000)
    .each(function(d, i) {
      d.complexValue = ((zz + i) % 4) * 20;
    })
    .attr("x", function(d) {
      return d.complexValue;
    })
    .attr("y", function(d) {
      return d.complexValue;
    })
};
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
<div id="demo"><svg width="360px"></svg></div>
<button onclick="each()">In an Each</button>
```

Comment: a-ha, I knew I'd be misunderstanding it somewhere, thanks!